# \write and pgfplotstable: Adding \pgfplotstableread into \loop goes wrong

Tags: pgfplotstable, write

I get a code from @DavidCarlisle, that generate output-txt-files, and I want to put all the outputfiles in a pgfplotstable together. 
 So I try adding 
`\ifnum\the\filecount=1 \pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{data1.txt}{\main} \else {.........} \fi`

But this gives only some strange Omegas and `\pgfplotstabletypeset[col sep=comma]{\main}` does not work.

What have I to do?

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\newcount\filecount
\newwrite\cisout
\begin{document}

{
\endlinechar=\newlinechar%
\filecount=1 %
\def\aaa{file number \the\filecount}%
\loop%
\immediate\openout\cisout=data\the\filecount.txt %
\immediate\write\cisout{%
111, 222,   \aaa 
}%
\immediate\closeout\cisout %
\advance\filecount by 1 %
\ifnum\filecount<5 %
\ifnum\the\filecount=1 \pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{data1.txt}{\main} \else\fi
\repeat %
}%

\section{pgfplotstable Test - bad}
%\pgfplotstabletypeset[col sep=comma]{\main}
\dots and some bad Omegas above\dots

\section{input Test - good}
\input{data1.txt}
\input{data3.txt}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma,header=false]{data1.txt}{\main}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[col sep=comma,string type]{\main}` works for me.

Comment: `\ifnum\the\filecount=1 \pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{data1.txt}{\main} \else\fi` is never going to be true as you start with filecount=1 and  you increment it two lines above this test so it will never be less than 2.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, @ Schrödinger'scat   I am not able to fix it.

Comment: you haven't said what you want to do, do you just want to read the first file or read them all? Either way move the tableread command to before the \advance\filecount, but after the \closeout. Also why write the data to the filesystem then read it back isn't that just making things slow for no reason?

Comment: I need a method to create a pgfplotstable by rows - the code here is only the MWE-base for that. So for the problem here: I need a pgfplotstable with all the outpufiles as rows.   I think I have done what you said and moved \pgfplotstableread to serveral positions. But something is not going to work at mine.

Comment: What's the reason for `\endlinechar=\newlinechar`? And what's `\main`?

Comment: @egreg  Ah, '\main' is the name of the pgfplotstable. The other stuff is the hard work from Mr. Carlisle. ;)

Comment: @egreg it's obeylines (as far as I understood the original, slightly different, question in chat)

Comment: @cis but `\write` always write whole files, it can not append so you can't build up a file by rows, also it still isn't clear why you are using files at all, why don't you just define `\main` directly, why write a text file then read it back????

Comment: @DavidCarlisle OK, the reason is: I do not know, how to create 1 textfile (by adding line for line). But I understand your  code so far...     If I could get the same with 1 textfile, ok.....   BTW: Could anybody post a runable MWE? I am to dump.

Comment: why do you need a text file at all? surely you can just generate `\main` then  pass it to `pgfplotstabletypeset` for typesetting, but it is hard to answer as you haven't said what the code is supposed to do, only that it isn't working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing `\ifnum\filecount=1` when the counter has already been advanced, so the code for `\pgfplotstableread` is never executed.

Besides, even if you manage to execute it, the whole `\loop` is in a group, so `\main` will be forgotten at the end of the group.

The Omegas were produced because `\fi` was not followed by `%`.

Here's a working code, although it's not clear what your aim is.

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\newcount\filecount
\newwrite\cisout

\begin{document}

\filecount=1
\def\aaa{file number \the\filecount}%
\loop
\immediate\openout\cisout=data\the\filecount.txt
\immediate\write\cisout{%
111, 222,   \aaa
}
\immediate\closeout\cisout
\ifnum\the\filecount=1 \pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{data1.txt}{\main}\fi
\advance\filecount by 1
\ifnum\filecount<5
\repeat

\section{pgfplotstable Test - bad}

\pgfplotstabletypeset[col sep=comma]{\main}

\section{input Test - good}
\input{data1.txt}
\input{data3.txt}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh... Could you add please that every row, the loop creates, is added to \main?   I got the next problem with `\pgfplotstablevertcat{\main}{\temp}` after "\else"

Comment: @cis Why not writing a single file?

Comment: Yes, Mr. Carlisle ask the same; but I do not know how to do that with "openout-write-loop-..." command.    With other words: I don not know, how to create '1' textfile and add rows per loop.

Comment: Ouuhh and very important:    I need for my algorithm the content of previous rows to be computated in later rows!!!

Comment: Thank you very much. I think, it is better to close here. I will make a follow-up question. ;)

Comment: Follow-up question:  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/519465/newwrite-pgfplotstable-put-generated-rows-together-to-one-pgfplotstable-foll

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately, is this what you are trying to achieve?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\newcount\filecount
\newwrite\cisout
\begin{document}

{
\filecount=0
\immediate\openout\cisout=data1.txt
\immediate\write\cisout{a, b, c}% write header
\loop\ifnum\filecount<5
  \advance\filecount by 1
  \immediate\write\cisout{111, 222, \the\filecount }%
\repeat% no \fi needed
\immediate\closeout\cisout

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{data1.txt}{\main}%

\pgfplotstabletypeset\main
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

---

This version uses `\foreach`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\newwrite\cisout

\begin{document}
\immediate\openout\cisout=data1.txt
\immediate\write\cisout{a, b, c}% write header
\foreach \i in {1,..., 5}%
  {\immediate\write\cisout{111, 222, \i }}%
\immediate\closeout\cisout

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{data1.txt}{\main}%

\pgfplotstabletypeset\main
\end{document}
```